# Flurry iOS crash reporting analytics

Tags: ios, flurry

I have been trying to test crash reports using Flurry for the past few days on iPad app using Flurry but haven’t had much success. When I view the Flurry dashboard online, its not showing any crash reports.  Although I can see other events being registered in  Flurry Dashboard but not crash reports. Below is the code which I am  using in AppDelegate to enable crash reports using flurry.

```
//Step 1: This should be done before you start session
[Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];

//Step 2:
[Flurry startSession:flurryToken];
[Flurry setSecureTransportEnabled:YES];
[Flurry setShowErrorInLogEnabled:YES];
[Flurry setDebugLogEnabled:YES];
[Flurry setBackgroundSessionEnabled:NO];
```

Below are the steps that I have used to test on iPad

- Run my app on iPad
- Cause crash on one of the screen
- Re-run the app
- Press the home screen to put in the background

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thnx.

Comment: Its seems to be working now, I created a ticket with flurry, they confirmed that it could take several hours before it could show in the dashboard.

Comment: Flurry confirmed that it could take around 7-8 hours to show in dashboard.

Comment: setSecureTransportEnabled is not working any more? I am  getting Type 'Flurry' has no member 'setSecureTransportEnabled'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its seems to be working now, I created a ticket with flurry, they confirmed that it could take about 8 hours before it could show in the dashboard.

Comment: Can you  mention the steps that how to create ticket or How can I enable flurry creash reports in my application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `[Flurry startSession: flurryToken];` last. At least one of your methods subsequent to your startSession call needs to be called before startSession.

[See, for example, documentation for `setSecureTransportEnabled:`](http://support.flurry.com/sdkdocs/iOS/interface_flurry_analytics.html)

Comment: Check my response above, it seems to be working now. Thnx for the reference.