# Flurry Crash Reporting not working

Tags: ios, swift, flurry

[image: These are the logs in log console]I have tried like below in my app delegate. Can you please tell me what's going wrong here:

```
    Flurry.setDebugLogEnabled(true)
    Flurry.setLogLevel(FlurryLogLevelDebug)
    Flurry.setEventLoggingEnabled(true)
    Flurry.setBackgroundSessionEnabled(true)
    Flurry.setCrashReportingEnabled(true)
    Flurry.setShowErrorInLogEnabled(true)
    Flurry.startSession("KEY")
```

Comment: when you upload app on appstore you have remove Flurry.setDebugLogEnabled(true) in live build

Comment: It's ok but right now it is in development phase.

Comment: You have the right API key in there where it says "KEY"?

Comment: @William GP Yes I have and put it carefully over there in my application here I didn't keep that.

Comment: In the first row it says WatchConnectivity is not linked. Are you building an app for the iWatch?

Comment: No it's just simple iphone application.

Comment: What exactly is it that isn't working? If you're provoking a crash nothing is being sent or what do you mean?

Comment: I got any crash in my app it's not showing on crash dashboard but it showing me started session and end session and other informations perfect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23955860/3981769 take a look at this

Comment: TMob can you please guide me how can i create ticket? and I already check out this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109621/discussion-between-tmob-and-jecky).

Comment: Check whether you have added security.framework and systemconfiguration.framework in build phases/link binary with libraries

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23955860/3981769) please check with the support from Flurry first, to make sure that this isn't normal behaviour. The post also states that it can take up to 8 hours for a crash to appear in the dashboard.

Flurry support page : https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/support.html

Make sure to include your API-key in the email, so they can actually check on your problem.